# Possible incompatibility between glossaries-extra (bib2gls) and totcount (\newtotcounter)

Tags: incompatibility, glossaries-extra, bib2gls, totcount, overflow

In current MiKTeX distribution (both release and pre-release), compiling the following code leads to `java.lang.StackOverflowError` that, according to `bib2gls`’s manual, may be caused by an infinite loop.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{entries.bib}
@entry{bird,
  name={bird},
  description = {feathered animal}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src=entries]

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{tc}

\begin{document}
\gls{bird}
\printunsrtglossaries
\end{document}
```

### Messages

> ```
> Process started: bib2gls "document"
>
> bib2gls version 2.3 (2020-03-23)
>
> Reading document.aux
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> at java.util.Vector.iterator(Unknown Source)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.TeXObjectList.clone(TeXObjectList.java:1392)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.TeXObjectList.expandfully(TeXObjectList.java:1514)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.Group.expandfully(Group.java:222)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.primitives.If.doTruePart(If.java:175)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.primitives.If.doTruePart(If.java:211)
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.primitives.If.doTruePart(If.java:211)
>   ⋮   [1017 more nestings]
> at com.dickimawbooks.texparserlib.primitives.If.doTruePart(If.java:211)
>
> Process exited with errors
>
>
> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex
>
> Process exited normally
> ```

---

The problem indicates possible incompatibility between `bib2gls 2.3 2020-03-23` and `\newtotcounter{}` of `totcount 1.2` or some other macros/packages that it invokes.

It seems to be related to the second line of the AUX file:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@tc@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{tc@totc}\fi\setcounter{tc@totc}{0}
```

as changing it to:

```
\newcounter{tc@totc}\setcounter{tc@totc}{0}
```

reverts normal operation of `bib2gls`.

Also, reordering commands in preamble does not prevent these errors from occurring.

Comment: bib2gls seems not to like the \expandafter. That is imho a clear bug and you should report it.

Comment: Reported [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bug-report.php).
It may not be caused by `\expandafter` (at least not by the one directly present in AUX), as changing the line to `\if11\newcounter{tc@totc}\fi\setcounter{tc@totc}{0}` does not solve the issue.

Comment: well the error disappeared for me if I removed the \expandafter. But it doesn't matter much, bib2gls shouldn't crash on a valid aux-file.

Comment: I'm not sure if you reported at the right place. The github of bib2gls is here: https://github.com/nlct/bib2gls

Comment: The author of both packages [has addressed the report](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?action=view&key=161) and traced the bug to the (La)TeX parser used by `bib2gls`. The issue has been [migrated to GitHub](https://github.com/nlct/texparser/issues/3) and [fixed](https://github.com/nlct/texparser/commit/1afa9708f54dfeccb02fcfc946a36721eb38a427).